# How to send JSON dict in POST request?

Tags: objective-c, json, http-post, nsarray, httprequest

I have this JSON dictionary:

```
{"userId":"363008505", "userName":"almogsh11", "friends":[{"u":"2079823612","n":"she43"},{"u":"2010211025","n":"temy63c"}]}
```

It contains the "friends" array. I want to send this dictionary in post http request to server.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) framework. There are a couple of methods you could use, such as [JSON Parameter Encoding](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#json-parameter-encoding) and [URL Form Parameter Encoding](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#url-form-parameter-encoding).